# Pycharm vs. cmd terminal have different output

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm

I have a program that tracks orders through the DHL API. It works fantastic in PyCharm, but when I run the program in cmd, it gets an error.

I figured the most obvious problem was that PyCharm and cmd were using different types of python, so I added print(platform.python_version()), and alas, Pycharm was using 3.6.5 and cmd was using 3.6.4. I switched cmd to 3.6.5, and I'm still getting the same different results. I kept the print statement included, and they are both 3.6.5. I know I'm running the same file.

My code itself works, the problem is in PyCharm vs. cmd and the Python version being used, so the code won't help at all.

This is the error message I'm getting on cmd:

```
Iterator operand 1 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[us]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'
```

That's an error regarding NumPy and converting texts to a date format. I'm not as concerned with that error specifically, just the fact that they are having a different output. Thank you for any help.

Comment: dude, maybe you need virtualenvwrapper or pipenv..unify the python and python environment in both pycharm and commandline..good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're running the same file in different Python environments, which would why the behavior is different. 
There are a couple of ways you can verify this. First, check which interpreter your PyCharm project is using by navigating (on Windows) to `File` --> `Settings` --> `Project: <YourProjectName>` --> `Project Interpreter`.
This will list the interpreter path. If it's a virtualenv, try activating it in your cmd terminal and see if you still get the difference in behavior. Same if it's a Conda environment.

Another thing you could do (and is generally considered a good idea) is to create a virtual environment that matches your PyCharm environment and use that in your cmd prompt. 
To do this, type the following in your PyCharm Terminal:

> pip list > requirements.txt

Then, in Windows CMD:

> python3 -m venv yourenv

To activate your new environment:

> .\yourenv\Scripts\activate

To install the Pycharm environment's packages:

> (yourenv) pip install -r requirements.txt

Then try running your project again. 
Hope that helps!